# How to select a subset of records derived from TWO tables from a larger set with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, subset

I can select students who sit exams in EITHER May or August, both not students who sit exams in BOTH May and August.

Here's how I get those who sit in EITHER of the sessions:

```
SELECT personal.LastName, personal.FirstName 
FROM personal
INNER JOIN exam
ON personal.P_ID = exam.P_ID
WHERE exam.Sitting IN ('B1May', 'B1Aug')
```

I am able to use nested clauses for other queries where the same target column exists in different tables - e.g.

```
SELECT TransactionID FROM payments WHERE TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM personal)
```

But so far I can't get anything with SELECT . . . WHERE . . . IN () . .  . to work for query that uses data from TWO tables.

Comment: `FROM personal, exam` note that this way to write joins is deprecated since about 25 years. Consider using proper [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've amended the query now.

Comment: Well, maybe not 'deprecated', but deeply unfashionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve this is to `COUNT` how many rows are returned for each person; a person who sat both exams will return 2 rows in the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName 
FROM personal p
JOIN exam e
ON p.P_ID = e.P_ID
WHERE e.Sitting IN ('B1May', 'B1Aug')
GROUP BY p.LastName, p.FirstName 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5925a6b7a8b54134b0735861c50a03f4)

Comment: Thanks, Nick! That's a breakthrough for me. It's also showing me people who sat more than one exam in the same session. It's possible for students to do a Partial exam and a Full exam, so I'm seeing results for people who did Partial and Full in August, for example. I'll play with your query to deal with that extra dimension.

Comment: @Benjamin no worries. With the info I had this was as good as I could do, but you should be able to work from here to include the other conditions you need.

Comment: Exactly. I'm on it now. Just needed a steer. Thanks again!